# Delay on show/hide menu and submenu jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have menu and submenu:

```js
$( ".my-menu ul li.has-children" ).on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').show().delay(1000).fadeOut();    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                   <a href="">Subitem 1</a>
                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">EEEEE</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Subitem 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

This show submenu with delay. But when I hover on item he's hide, why? I need show menu and submenu always, when cursor on menu or submenu..

Comment: the `.fadeOut()` will, well, fade it out. If you don't want that, remove the `.fadeOut()`

Comment: @RobinZigmond then not working hiding..

Comment: Well it's really not clear what you're trying to do. The code at the moment does exactly what it appears to be intended to, and you don't make it clear what the intention is.

Comment: use mouseleave event to hide

Comment: @RobinZigmond  I need on the hover to menu show this menu and submenu, when cursor not in menu element, then hide this menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use two functions 
for showing

```
$( ".my-menu ul li.has-children" ).on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').show().delay(1000);   
});
```

for hiding

```
$( ".my-menu ul li.has-children" ).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').fadeOut();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `hover` it accepts two functions: first for mouseenter and second for mouseleave. Here is an example:

```
$( ".my-menu ul li.has-children" ).hover(
  function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').show()   
  },
  function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').delay(1000).fadeOut();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".my-menu ul li.has-children").on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').show();
});
$(".sub-menu").on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Subitem 1</li>
                <li>Subitem 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: See please my updated question, this is not working for third sub-menu

Comment: Can you, please, explaint what exactly is not working? I've done jsfiddle for that purpose http://jsfiddle.net/Lnqa5rw3/ and I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: subitem is not hiding..  when mouseout

Comment: Have you checked that jsfiddle? It hides just as it should, as you trigger that same sub-menu mouseout-handler as for higher level sub-menus.

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseenter and mouseleave with fadeIn and fadeOut
Dont forget to set the .sub-menu style="display:none"

```js
$( ".my-menu ul li.has-children" ).on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').fadeIn();    
});
$( ".my-menu ul li.has-children" ).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').fadeOut();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update like this

```js
$( ".my-menu ul li.has-children" ).on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').delay(20).show();    
});

$( ".my-menu ul li.has-children" ).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').show().delay(20).fadeOut();    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul style="display: none;" class="sub-menu">
                <li>Subitem 1</li>
                <li>Subitem 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```